# ggplot2: How to plot 2 lines in a time frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question concerning ggplot2. I have my columns as followed:

```
      DF
     $TIME     $PRECIP      $DELAY
     08:00       200          250
     08:12       160          222 
     08:14       155          230
     08:31       100          200

     etc. etc.
```

$TIME is stated as characters. I would like to plot a graph where on the x-axis there is a time frame. For example between 04:00 and 23:50, with for steps every hour for example. And on the Y axis a range between 0 and 500. I can define the Yaxis range through

```
     coord_cartesian(xlim = ?, ylim = c(0,500))
```

How can I plot both lines directly in the same plot while having the X axis defined as between a certain time frame so that I can view the progress of precipitation and delay during a day?

Comment: Turn your `TIME` column into a `datetime` object (see `?as.POSIXct`---just put it on some date, like today or Jan 1 2020), and the defaults will make nice, customizable with `scale_x_datetime`.

Comment: I have this, but Im not sure what Im doing wrong: `datetime <- as.POSIXct(DF$TIME, format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M', tz = Sys.timezone())`

Comment: Try `datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste("2020-01-01", DF$TIME), format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M', tz = Sys.timezone())`. You need a date as well as a time, but it doesn't really matter what date you choose.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works!